# Html and css. My div class doesn't react to css

Tags: html, css

I created a div class and called it `.center` in CSS. When doing all the styling it doesn't react when shown in browser. I made the exact same thing with the same code when creating the home page. However when I do the same thing for the second page nothing happens.

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: -25%;
  top: 85%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="cursor:pointer; position: absolute; width: 59px; height: 42px; left: 687px; top: 29px;" onclick="openNav()">
  <div class="fa fa-angle-double-down" style="font-size:50px; color:white; hover: black;"></div>
  <div class="center">Menu</div>
</div>
```

I have the same attributes for the homepage and the menu text is white with the font family and have the hover effect. However on this page it doesn't react to the CSS it's just plain black with standard font.

Comment: Where did you define "openNav()"?

Comment: Also did you properly include this css file so it's being used by your html? (not sure what type of project this is angular/react/native etc.)

Comment: Did you add css file in your html page?

Comment: Right now it's hard to see anything, since you've got white text on a white background :). Also, things are positioned absolutely, which makes it hard to tell what's supposed to be shown. You have no `:hover` pseudo class in your CSS, so I'm not sure what the "hover effect" is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Your div.center is positioned absolutely in relation to its parent. Do this:

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: just changed the colors, so you can see whats happening

Comment: This didn’t do anything. Thank’s for the adivce though